# Как найти максимум из трёх чисел, используя this?

Tags: java

Создайте класс, который находит наибольшее из трех чисел.
Ко всем переменным можно обращаться, ТОЛЬКО используя `this`.

Не пойму, как здесь использовать `this`?

Вот моя попытка:

```java
public class class4 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       MaxOf3Num maxOf3Num = new MaxOf3Num();
       int x = 3;
       int y = 8;
       int z = 4;
       maxOf3Num.findMax(x,y,z);
```

```java
public class MaxOf3Num {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    void findMax (int a, int b, int c) {

        if (a > b && a > c) {
            System.out.println( a);
        } else if (b > c) {
            System.out.println( b);

        } else {
            System.out.println( c);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Предположу, что нужно сделать конструктор, который принимает `a`, `b`, `c` и раскидывает по соотвесттвующим переменным. А метод `findMax` будет без аргументов и обращение внутри метода будет через `this.a`, `this.b`, `this.c`

Answer (score 0):

В представленной вами реализации метод `findMax` не использует соответствующие поля класса `MaxOf3Num`, которые к тому же нигде в коде не инициализируются.  Поэтому сравнение выполняется для параметров указанного метода, и в худшем случае будут использоваться три операции сравнения, хотя поиска максимума трёх чисел достаточно двух сравнений.

Также для данного метода в представленной реализации больше подходит название `printMax`, так как он вместо возврата требуемого максимума просто печатает его.

С учётом вышесказанного, код класса `MaxOf3Num` следует переписать, как указал @Алексей Шиманский в своём ответе:

- "спрятать" переменные и потребовать их обязательной инициализации, использовав `private final`
- добавить конструктор для обязательной инициализации полей класса (будет использоваться `this`)
- реализовать метод без параметров (`this` использовать необязательно, так как в данном контексте метод и так будет обращаться к соответствующим полям класса)

```java
public class MaxOf3Num {
    private final int a, b, c;

    // конструктор с обязательными аргументами
    public MaxOf3Num(int a, int b, int c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    // два сравнения
    public int findMax() {
        int max = a > b ? a : b;
        return c > max ? c : max;
    }

    public int findMax2() {
        return Math.max(Math.max(this.a, this.b), this.c); // this необязательно
    }
}
```

Тогда поиск максимума будет выглядеть так:

```java
System.out.println(new MaxOf3Num(3, 8, 4).findMax()); // 8
```